# Child Theme Index.php won't override parent theme

Tags: wordpress

So I've built several sites like this, using a child theme to be able to customize what I want.

This time, I have a child theme directory with a style.css and functions.php, etc.

The style sheet overrides fine, even the header.php I added overrides. However, index.php will not override the parent theme's index.php.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How did you go with this @Matthew?

Comment: I actually had to re-install wordpress and it worked fine!

Comment: Cool, glad you solved it! Just had a look thru some of your questions here, if the answers have helped you please consider accepting one by clicking the tick next to the answer - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for help on how this works at StackOverflow. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you've set everything up correctly, from the fact that your header.php is overriding the parent theme.

The index.php template is the final fallback if Wordpress cannot find a more appropriate template to use. Most likely, it's selecting another template from the parent theme - eg. archive.php, frontpage.php, home.php, single.php - or many others depending on which particular URL you are viewing.

[This visual overview](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview) of Wordpress' template hierarchy will help you understand how it works. Using this, you should be able to locate which template file is being selected in the parent theme and therefore, which one you need to override.

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing!